# ngModelの入力を半角文字だけを入力できるようにしたい

Tags: angular4

全角の文字を入力させないようにしたくpatternなどで試してみたのですが、
全角も入力ができてしまったため、パイプを使ったらどうかと思い、
入力値の変換パイプを用意しましたが、以下のようなエラーが出てしまします。

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{testText | test-pipe}}]
```

ngModelの入力値に対してのパイプによる変換はできないでしょうか？

test-pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'test-pipe'
})

export class TestPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): string {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      return valueの半角文字以外をreplaceしたものを返す
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

表示するhtml

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="{{testText | test-pipe}}">
```

表示するモジュール

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    TestPipe,
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

入力値をパイプで処理してinputに戻すには、次のように書きます。

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="testText | test-pipe" (ngModelChange)="testText=$event" />
```

イベントバインディングで入力値を受け取り、プロパティバインディングでパイプで処理してinputに戻します。
プロパティバインディングはコンポーネント→ビューの片方向バインディングとするのが重要ですね。

Comment: shimiteiさま、ありがとうございます。バインディングがまだ完全に理解できず、もう少しいろいろ試してみようと思います。